# Veal and peppers

Tags: stews, braising, veal

I have a recipe using veal with peppers, white wine, and stock in pan. The meat called for is veal stew meat. I have prepared this with both stew meat and veal cutlets. The stew meat is stringy, and the cutlets seem to be a bit too tough (over-cooked?).

The recipe calls for heating the oil, cooking the vegetables, adding the meat and browning, then adding the wine quick, and the stock and letting it cook (braise?).

Should I try different stew meat, or just make sure cutlets are seared and cooked quick? Or just let the stew meat stew for much longer over low heat to become tender?

The dish itself is delicious .

Comment: Could you define "cutlet"? Between various countries I think the term means at least four different things.

Answer (score 2):

I think the recipe should mention the actual cut. But a rule of thumb is:
If you’re cooking tender cuts, then you should *not* cok for an extended period.

If you’re cooking tougher cuts, you *should* cook for an extended period, until you get your desired tenderness.